# using json parser how to access the tableview cell and display corresponding PDF Files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, ios6

Hi i am developing one application using `UITableview`. My requirment is to click the tableview cell to navigate detailview controller and display corresponding PDF File.

I have completed `UITableview` coding. My requirement is  using json parser to access the corresponding PDF URLS to display the data.

so plz any body help how to develop the code using json parser to display corresponding tableviewcell pdf file. Send me any sample code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You Must Do Following Steps

1. Study About JSON Parser and Store Values to Corresponding Arrays.
2. Using This Array Values and Fill the Tableview Cells.
3. Then click the DidSelectRow you can get corresponding Array value using IndexPath.row, then Pass values to Another View controller.
4. The PDF viewConroller You can display PDF in the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is an interesting tutorial by Ray](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5) which explains well about json and how to use in application